# Uploading SSL Certificate to AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My SSL Certificate on my AWS Elastic Load Balancer is going to expire very soon and I need to replace it with a new one.

I've got the new certificate / bundle / key, uploaded to IAM but it won't show in the drop down in the Load Balancer settings that should let me choose the certificate to apply.

Here is the output when I put
    aws iam list-server-certificates

[image]

To my mind this shows that I have uploaded the new certificate to IAM ok. The top certificate in the list is the one which is due to expire any moment now and the other two are ones I have recently uploaded with the intention of replacing it (They are actually two attempts to upload using the same pem files).

The image below shows that only one certificate is available to choose to apply to the load balancer. Unfortunately it is the one that is about to expire.

[image]

The one thing that does strike me as a little odd is that the certificate name in the dropdown - ptdsslcert - is different to the names in the aws iam list-server-certificates output, even though it is the same certificate that expires imminently.

I'm really stuck here and if I don't figure this out soon I'm going to have an expired certificate on my domain so I would be really appreciative of any help on this.

Comment: In the certificate ARN, `arn:aws:iam:xxx`, xxx is your AWS account number.  In the console, top right, there's a dropdown with your name.  From there, "My Account" will show you the account ID.  If that number doesn't match the value shown in your screenshot in the ARN, then your `aws cli` is not connecting to the same AWS account as you're using in the console.  So far, that's the only scenario I have come up with to explain what you are seeing.  The cli `ServerCertificateName` on my certs matches what shows in the console dropdown.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for the reply. I think that is exactly what is happening but it didn't cross my mind until you suggested it. I have an old aws account as well which I no longer use and the number in the ARN is the account number for that account not the one I use now... contd vvv

Comment: But how is this happening? I use the command line interface most days to use git to upload new versions with no problems... Although, i don't like using it for anything else. Is it possible it is using one account for uploading versions and another for IAM? Or that it is set up for the old account but is somehow managing to upload versions to the new account anyway??

Comment: Ok... So I set up a new user in the correct account and reconfigured my aws command line for this user.... and hey Presto it worked! Thanks so much for your help @Michael-sqlbot. It would not have been good at all for my ssl cert to expire and now it won't - you really saved me! I'm still not entirely sure how I was happily uploading versions to elastic beanstalk all this time while configured for a different account!? Maybe the eb cli config is different?? Time to learn a bit more about it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The AWS CLI uses a *provider chain* to look for AWS credentials in a number of different places, including system or user environment variables and local AWS configuration files.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Although it's hard to guess the specific local machine configuration issue that resulted in the behavior observed, as noted in the comments, this appeared to be an issue where `aws cli` was using two different sets of credentials to access two different services, and these two sets of credentials were actually from two different AWS accounts.

The `ServerCertificateName` returned by the API (accessed through the CLI) should have matched the certificate name shown in the console drop-down for Elastic Load Balancer certificate selection.

The composition of ARNs (Amazon Resource Names) varies by service, but often includes the AWS account number.  In this case, the account number shown in the CLI output did not match what was visible in the AWS console... leading to the conclusion that the issue was that an AWS account other than the intended one was being accessed by `aws cli`.

As cross-confirmed by the differing display names, the "existing" certificate, uploaded a year ago, may have had the same content but was in fact a different IAM entity than the one seen in the dropdown, as the two certificates were associated with entirely different accounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help pointing out what was happening and for the informative answer. Disaster averted!

Comment: I guess a similar mistake must have happened last year with the certificate being uploaded to the wrong account first.